# Do URLs submitted in a site map to reindex have the same priority as request indexing?

Tags: seo, google, google-search-console, google-search, url

Will Google position the URLs with same page rank in both cases?
Which is fast and good?
Will all URLs in the site map get indexed?

Comment: What do you mean by "request indexing"?   I've never heard of that before

Comment: "request indexing" - I assume you mean the the "Request indexing" option in GSC after having used the "Fetch as Google" tool. (?)

Answer (score 1):

You have included few things in the question, the following should clarify.

**XML Sitemap:** 
When you submit XML sitemap, Google algorithm reviews it and it will index pages based on its algorithm. ***There is no guarantee that it will index all submitted URLs.***

**XML Sitemap Priority:**
It only lets the search engines know which pages you want for the crawlers understand in terms of priority. The priority you assign doesn't influence ranking.

**Re-Indexing:**
Google algorithm re-crawls pages in certain interval regardless you submit xml sitemap or not.

**How to get crawled fast:**
There are several factors you can consider like:

- Have HTML sitemap, still very handy search engines.
- Do internal linking from important pages based on your priority.
- Submit XML sitemap
- Share pages on social media sites, G+ is an important to place to start.
- Build authority in general which can also influence fast crawling.

Comment: Sitemaps are generally only used to audit that Google can effectively crawl a site. Where a sitemaps have a real benefit is for extremely huge sites and sites that have content behind a login or pay wall.